# Program compiles on one server, doesn't on another

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm getting this error when I try and compile my program on my school's external server.

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
pow                                 /var/tmp//ccWbipvM.o
sqrt                                /var/tmp//ccWbipvM.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to assign1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The problem is I don't get it when I compile it locally - it runs fine. Can anyone give me some advice as to what the problem is here?? Thanks!

PS: math.h has been included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try *linking* your program with the math library by using the `-lm` flag:

```
gcc -o prg -lm prg.c
```